# How to find index of int element in array

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, find, element

everyone..
So I wanna find the index of an int element in array. but the element has 2 index (there is 2 index that have same element). How could I show the indexes for an element?

here is my `findIndex` code :

```java
public void setIndex(int[] bil, int a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < bil.length; i++) {
        if (bil[i] == a) {
            n = i;
        }
    }
}

public int getIndex() {
    return n;
}

public void show(int a) {
    System.out.println(a);
}

public void show(String a) {
    System.out.println(a);
    a = null;
}
```

and this is my code in main class :

```java
int deret[] = {-5, -3, -6, -3, -4};
array3 arr = new array3();

arr.show("\nIndex of -3 : ");
arr.setIndex(deret, -3);
arr.show(arr.getIndex());
```

if I use those code, the output will be :

```
Index of -3 :
3
```

How to show the index of both -3? like :

```
Index of -3 :
1, 3
```

Comment: You want to show? Or you want to keep and show?

Comment: @ScaryWombat is there any different? acctually I just need to show

Answer (score 0):

As you only need to show, you can do as you are processing

```
if (bil[i] == a) {
    System.out.print (i);
}
```

Comment: how about the return value? if i do code "System.out.print (i)" then my setIndex() method must be int method, not void. And if I change it to int method, it will error because we have to return a value.

Comment: And that is why I asked the question.  If you need to store then you will need some mechanism to hold more than one value e.g. An array.